# How to get the .index() of this.id

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to iterate through a class using `each()`. How can I get the `id` attached to that class and get it's index?

I tried to do it like this but `this.id` only returns that id name and not the actual id:

```js
$('.nav-click').each(function() {
    console.log($(this.id).index('.nav-click'));
 });
```

Comment: not `$(this.id)`, but `$(this)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `this` to reference the element:

```
$('.nav-click').each(function() {
  console.log(this.id); // the id attribute
  console.log($(this).index('.nav-click')); // the index of this element within the .nav-click set
});
```

Alternatively you can just use the `index` parameter as passed to the `each()` handler function:

```
$('.nav-click').each(function(i) {
  console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: Wow, definitely overthinking that one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index` and `attr` functions.

```js
$('.nav-click').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).index(), $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='nav-click' id='one'>one</p>
<p class='nav-click' id='two'>two</p>
```